# aurelia pages with different page formats

Tags: templates, aurelia

In the Aurelia SPA template it assumes that every page will be inside app.html and use the same nav-bar at the top. But I'll have many pages that don't want the nav-bar at the top and actually not use app.html at all. I was looking at main.js and it looks like I could hook into bootstrap() and change the aurelia.setRoot() for certain pages (I'm just guessing here), but then I start mucking up the main.js file and it won't be long before it gets really messy and maintenance headache. I really just want to have some pages use their own format altogether and ignore the app.html formatting without doing any crazy configurations.

My initial thought is maybe app.html should just be an empty file and make every page  decide whether or not it wants the nav-bar and include it on the individual pages. But now I'm duplicating the code across many pages and if the standard page layout changes I have to change all the individual pages. Not sure the best way to go about his.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using set root, like you said, is a bad idea. Similar to what you said, you can make app.html contain just the router view tag. Different parts of your app, that you want to share a similar page layout, will be gruped under different routes. Now each of theses routes will point to another router that will have its different styles in the view

Just think of it as an empty app.html with child app.html's that have styles in them(e.g. Different navbars, page layout etc)

Answer (score 2):

I actually disagree with Gilbert's answer. Using `.setRoot` is a best practice; the root is just the parent view/viewModel pair and you will often have different parents. This is essentially what you're doing when you're creating an empty app view/viewModel, creating a new parent that doesn't do anything. But adding an unnecessary, unused layer is just extra complication.

One of the best use cases for this is a login page. The login page is totally different from your normal app page--there's a login prompt, no navigation bar, etc. Therefore, make a "login" app root and a "app" app root and switch back and forth between them. I've built a template called Sentry that demonstrates how to do this.

[Sentry in action](https://foursails.github.io/sentry/)

[Sentry on GitHub](https://github.com/foursails/sentry)

Comment: .setRoot is indeed useful. I use it in my apps too where i need to restrict access to specific sections of my apps(i.e. login root and main app root). Concerning your statement :"But adding an unnecessary, unused layer is just extra complication", using .setRoot will point to a file with a router. My example does the same. I prefer my approach because i can map routes to <a> tags instead of calling .setRoot from the viewModel.